# HTML email not responsive on Apple Mail

Tags: html, css, email, media-queries, responsive

I've built an email template that works beautifully in almost every place except Apple Mail, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

The issue is a section of columns that are supposed to stack on mobile. I've built them by following [this guide](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/responsive-column-layouts/) by Mailchimp.

Here is the section for the columns:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateColumns" style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="600">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="templateColumnContainer" valign="top" width="50%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="leftColumnContent">
                        <img alt="Placeholder" class="columnImage" src="https://go.frazerconsultants.com/l/43262/2020-08-31/9klwjc/43262/253944/540x400_Placeholder.png" style="font-size: 17; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; max-width: 280px;" width="280">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="leftColumnContent" style="color: #404040;" valign="top">
                        <h3 style="font-family: 'Lora', Georgia, serif;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h3>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p style="font-size: 17; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p><a href="https://frazerconsultants.com/" style="font-size: 17; line-height: 1.8em; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #404040; margin: 0; text-decoration: underline;">Read More</a></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="center" class="templateColumnContainer" valign="top" width="50%">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rightColumnContent">
                        <img alt="Placeholder" class="columnImage" src="https://go.frazerconsultants.com/l/43262/2020-08-31/9klwjc/43262/253944/540x400_Placeholder.png" style="font-size: 17; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; max-width: 280px;" width="280">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rightColumnContent" style="color: #404040;" valign="top">
                        <h3 style="font-family: 'Lora', Georgia, serif;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h3>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p style="font-size: 17; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p><a href="https://frazerconsultants.com/" style="font-size: 17; line-height: 1.8em; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #404040; margin: 0; text-decoration: underline;">Read More</a></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And here is the code I have in the head to make it responsive:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {

#templateColumns{
  width: 100% !important;
}

.templateColumnContainer{
  display: block !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.columnImage{
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 580px !important;
}

.leftColumnContent{
  font-size: 17px !important;
  line-height: 125% !important;
}

.rightColumnContent{
  font-size: 17px !important;
  line-height: 125% !important;
}
```

As expected, it doesn't work on the Gmail app because of the media queries, which is fine. Can't win them all.

It works great on the Outlook app:
[Outlook App on iOS/iPhone 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUkPH.jpg)

It doesn't work on the Apple Mail app:
[Apple Mail App on iOS/iPhone 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlPJj.jpg)

Basically the right column doesn't wrap onto a new line, it just gets super skinny and remains next to the left column.

I don't want to post a bunch of the rest of the code of the email because I feel like it would just make things too complicated, but I can add more if this isn't enough context.

Edited to add:

I did find kind of a buggy way to make it responsive on the Outlook app ONLY by adding [data-outlook-cycle] in front of the ids/classes in the media query section. At the very least it makes it legible in both Mail and Outlook but ideally I'd like the email to be responsive in Mail as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this actually works fine, I put it into a full document and added some of the usual base template elements, as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, date=no, address=no, email=no">
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {

      #templateColumns{
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      .templateColumnContainer{
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      .columnImage{
        height: auto !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 580px !important;
      }

      .leftColumnContent{
        font-size: 17px !important;
        line-height: 125% !important;
      }

      .rightColumnContent{
        font-size: 17px !important;
        line-height: 125% !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="body">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateColumns" style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="templateColumnContainer" valign="top" width="50%">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="leftColumnContent">
                            <img alt="Placeholder" class="columnImage" src="https://go.frazerconsultants.com/l/43262/2020-08-31/9klwjc/43262/253944/540x400_Placeholder.png" style="font-size: 17; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; max-width: 280px;" width="280">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="leftColumnContent" style="color: #404040;" valign="top">
                            <h3 style="font-family: 'Lora', Georgia, serif;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h3>
    
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
                            <p style="font-size: 17; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
                            <p><a href="https://frazerconsultants.com/" style="font-size: 17; line-height: 1.8em; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #404040; margin: 0; text-decoration: underline;">Read More</a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td align="center" class="templateColumnContainer" valign="top" width="50%">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="rightColumnContent">
                            <img alt="Placeholder" class="columnImage" src="https://go.frazerconsultants.com/l/43262/2020-08-31/9klwjc/43262/253944/540x400_Placeholder.png" style="font-size: 17; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; max-width: 280px;" width="280">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="rightColumnContent" style="color: #404040;" valign="top">
                            <h3 style="font-family: 'Lora', Georgia, serif;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h3>
    
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
                            <p style="font-size: 17; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
                            <p><a href="https://frazerconsultants.com/" style="font-size: 17; line-height: 1.8em; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #404040; margin: 0; text-decoration: underline;">Read More</a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

For me this stacks in the Gmail app (as long as it's a Gmail address, for non-Gmail addresses it will not apply the media queries), as well as the Outlook app, and the native iOS Mail app.

Could the problem be somewhere else in your document?

Comment: Thanks Nicole! Because of your comment I did some process of elimination elsewhere and discovered that the issue was the doctype declaration: <!DOCTYPE  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

After updating it started working beautifully!